# Multirow table help

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to build a table like this in Latex but I am new to this program and, even though I have read many blogs, I cannot understand how to build a table like this
Thank you in advance for your time

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is for sure duplicate ... but now I'm to lazy to find the same question here ;-). So, an example of use of `multirow` package is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{l|} }
    \hline
    &   & aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{LR}
    & 1 &   &   &   &   \\  \cline{2-6}
    & 2 &   &   &   &   \\  \cline{2-6}
    & 2 &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{SV}
    & 1 &   &   &   &   \\  \cline{2-6}
    & 2 &   &   &   &   \\  \cline{2-6}
    & 2 &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{6}{l}}[hvlines]
    &   & aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd \\
\Block{3-1}{LR}
    & 1 \\
    & 2 \\
    & 2 \\
\Block{3-1}{SV}
    & 1 \\
    & 2 \\
    & 2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]